# how to transform time codes into turn codes

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, lubridate

I want to transform time codes like these

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

df_time <- tibble(time = c(ymd_hms("2020_01_01 00:00:01"),
                           ymd_hms("2020_01_01 00:00:02"),
                           ymd_hms("2020_01_01 00:00:03"),
                           ymd_hms("2020_01_01 00:00:04"),
                           ymd_hms("2020_01_01 00:00:05"),
                           ymd_hms("2020_01_01 00:00:06")),
                  a = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
                  b = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0))
```

resulting in

```
>df_time
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  time                    a     b
  <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-01-01 00:00:01     0     0
2 2020-01-01 00:00:02     1     0
3 2020-01-01 00:00:03     1     1
4 2020-01-01 00:00:04     1     1
5 2020-01-01 00:00:05     1     0
6 2020-01-01 00:00:06     0     0
```

into turn codes (a.k.a. event codes/"start stop data"). Should look like the following df:

```
df_turn <- tibble(start = c(ymd_hms("2020_01_01 00:00:02"),
                            ymd_hms("2020_01_01 00:00:03")),
                  end = c(ymd_hms("2020_01_01 00:00:05"),
                          ymd_hms("2020_01_01 00:00:04")),
                  code = c("a", "b"))


> df_turn
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  start               end                 code 
  <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>
1 2020-01-01 00:00:02 2020-01-01 00:00:05 a    
2 2020-01-01 00:00:03 2020-01-01 00:00:04 b
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to convert your data frame to long and filter out the 0s. Once you do that, you only need the maximum and minimum per group (as per `time`), so we can do that using `slice` after we group. The final step is to create a column with `start` and `end` and simply convert the resulting data frame to wide format, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_time %>% 
 pivot_longer(cols = -1, names_to = 'code') %>% 
 filter(value != 0) %>% 
 group_by(code) %>%
 slice(c(which.min(time), which.max(time))) %>% 
 select(-value) %>% 
 mutate(new = c('start', 'end')) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = new, values_from = time)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 3
> # Groups:   name [2]
>   code   start               end                
>   <chr> <dttm>              <dttm>             
> 1 a     2020-01-01 00:00:02 2020-01-01 00:00:05
> 2 b     2020-01-01 00:00:03 2020-01-01 00:00:04
> ```